# How to fix Rails locale issues when testing with Rspec, Capybara etc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, capybara, locale

Application works, but routes dont't match. Some were prepended with '/en', some weren't. I was stripping the '/en' part in my application controller but it appeared in url helpers in tests:

```
Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/outgoing> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/en/outgoing>.
Expected "http://test.host/outgoing" to be === "http://test.host/en/outgoing".
```

Tried to add `default: { locale: :en}` to `routes.rb` (Spoiler: Bad idea, don't do that). Test pass, but in the actual application half of the routes are missing locales.

Comment: Reword as a question, otherwise this is a blog post.

Answer (score 2):

This what helped: https://gist.github.com/firedev/8541276

```
# spec/support/routing_helper.rb

class ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::NamedRouteCollection::UrlHelper
  def call(t, args)
    t.url_for(handle_positional_args(t, args, { locale: nil }.merge( @options ), @segment_keys))
  end
end
```

`locale: nil` strips the locale bit from the generated paths so they become uniform both for helpers and app-generated paths.